Laravel Livewire 3 | get current route in component
I need route based header that why I want to check route on each request and then I display my header as per requirement.
public function render()
{
    dd(request()->route()); // testing request url here
    $banners = Banner::where('website_id',website()->id)->get();
    $banners_array = [];
    foreach ($banners as $key => $banner) {
        $banners_array[$key]['imgSrc'] = env('APP_URL').'/storage/'.$banner->image;
        $banners_array[$key]['imgAlt'] = $banner->title;
        $banners_array[$key]['heading'] = $banner->heading;
        $banners_array[$key]['subHeading'] = $banner->sub_heading;
        $banners_array[$key]['btn'] = $banner->btn;
        $banners_array[$key]['btnLink'] = $banner->btn_link;
    }
    $this->banners = $banners_array;
    return view('livewire.partials.nav-bar',[
        'placeholder' => $this->placeholder(),
        'categories' =>  Category::where('website_id',website()->id)->with('sub_categories')->get(),
    ]);
}


It should show me current route name or URL.

On your app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php File
Add this macro
URL::macro('livewire_current,' function () {
        if (request()->route()->named('livewire.update')) {
            $previousUrl = $this->previous();
            $previousRoute = app('router')->getRoutes()->match(request()->create($previousUrl));
            return $previousRoute->getName();
        } else {
            return request()->route()->getName();
        }
    });

And than you can get your current URL route name in your blade livewire component :
url()->livewire_current()

